# Fire Change Event source is NULL in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, onclick

When clicking an Button it need to perform click action in this action should perform change event at this event source is null

**My Code:**
**Multiview.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource() instanceof PushButton)
    {           
        PushButton pb = (PushButton)event.getSource(); 
        if (id.equals("New")) {                     
            int rowNO = startRow + tableModel.rows() - 1;
            Window.selectedRow = rowNO;
            Window.selectedNode = m_node;
            Window.tabNo = multicomponentVO.tabNo;
            Window.tabVO = tabfieldsVO;
            Window.selectedqueryID=queryID;
            Window.cVO = multicomponentVO;
            Window.selectedcVO=multicomponentVO;                                                        
            fireChange("viewnew");
        }
     }

   private void fireChange(String action) {
    this.action = action;
    if (changeListeners != null) {          
        changeListeners.fireChange(new ChangeEvent(){});
    }               
}
```

**Window.java**

```
@Override
public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {       
    Widget sender=(Widget)event.getSource();
    if(sender instanceof Multiview)
   {
       // some stuff
    }
```

My query is When firing change event in multiview.java it fires onchange in window.java but im getting event source is null.

Please anyone help to refine or resolve this query

Answer (score 0):

Several issues are contributing to this.

```
        changeListeners.fireChange(new ChangeEvent(){});
```

You've taken over how the even is supposed to be fired - instead of actually going through the event wiring that would do it right, you've made an object with no source, passed it to `fireChange` (which I bet is one of your own methods in `changeListeners`), though you don't have it listed, unless `Multiview.fireChange` is calling itself...?), and then are complaining that it has no source! Consider firing either from the widget (I'm assuming Mulitview is a widget), or making a handlerManager/eventBus inside Multiview and using that to send the event.

Next, you are firing a DOM event manually, which is a little weird - this is an event that is meant to be fired from user actions in the browser. Take a look at `ValueChangeEvent<T>` instead.